# android kotlin do work and wait for finish to perform another task

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to perform some work and wait for result. After I get the result I want to continue with code execution. I don't want to block UI thread.

for example I want to have in same function "doCoroutineWork" this:

```
//PseudoCode//

fun doCoroutineWork()
{
  val result = doSomeWorkInBackground
  someOtherFunctionCall(result)
}
```

So what I want to do is to execute some work when calling doSomeWorkInBackground, wait for the result and after that call new function someOtherFunctionCall with the result of the first one.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `lifecycleScope.launch{ val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { doSomeWorkInBackground() }; someOtherFunctionCall(result) }`

Comment: `suspend fun doCoroutineWork()...` you are missing the `suspend` keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should make `doCoroutineWork` a suspend function, like:
`suspend fun doCoroutineWork()`

Then you have to call this from a `coroutineScope`, in a lifecycleOwner (activity, fragment) you can call

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
  val result = doCoroutineWork()
  someOtherFunctionCall(result)
}
```

Or inside a ViewModel you have access to `viewModelScope`

Also with the use of `withContext(Dispatchers.XY)` you can switch the designated threads if you need

Comment: lifecycleScope gives me unresolved refference. Even when I add   implementation'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0' to gradle it still can't recognize it...

Comment: And with `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0`? See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#dependencies

Comment: Ok yes it now recognizes lifecycleScope but it still doesn't work well. App crashes when I make code your way. Also it tells me that suspend word in front of my function is not needed